# How to use variables in a bash for loop

Tags: linux, bash, for-loop

How does one use a variable in a bash for loop?
If I just use a standard for loop, it does what I expect

```
for i in {0..3}
do
   echo "do some stuff $i"
done
```

This works fine.  It loops thru 4 times, 0 to 3 inclusive, printing my message and putting the count at the end.

```
do some stuff 0
do some stuff 1
do some stuff 2
do some stuff 3
```

When I try the same thing with the following for loop, it seems to equal a string, which is not what i want.

```
length=3
for i in {0..$length}
do
   echo "do something right $i"
done
```

output:

```
do something right {0..3}
```

I've tried

```
for i in {0.."$length"} and for i in {0..${length}} (both output was {0..3})
```

and

```
for i in {0..'$length'} (output was {0..$length})
```

and they both don't do what I need.  Hopefully someone can help me.  Thanks in advance for any bash expert's help with for loops.

Comment: `zsh` is best suited for that :-)

Answer (score 166, accepted):

One way is using `eval`:

```
for i in $( eval echo {0..$length} )
do
       echo "do something right $i"
done
```

*Note* what happens when you set `length=;ls` or `length=; rm *` (don't try the latter though).

*safely*, using `seq`:

```
for i in $( seq 0 $length )
do
       echo "do something right $i"
done
```

or you can use the c-style for loop, which is also safe:

```
for (( i = 0; i <= $length; i++ )) 
do 
       echo "do something right $i"
done
```

Comment: It's possible to omit `$` sign in double parentheses to refer a variable

Answer (score 21):

In bash, brace expansion is the *first* step attempted so, at that point, `$length` will not have been substituted.

The manpage for bash states clearly:

> A  sequence expression takes the form {x..y[..incr]}, where x and y are **either integers or single characters** ...

There are a number of possibilities, such as using:

```
pax> for i in $(seq 0 $length) ; do echo $i ; done
0
1
2
3
```

though that may give you a large command line if `length` is massive.

Another alternative is to use the C-like syntax:

```
pax> for (( i = 0; i <= $length; i++ )) ; do echo $i; done
0
1
2
3
```

It's also possible to omit `$` sign in **double parentheses** to refer a variable:

```
ubuntu@ip-172-31-28-53:~/playground$ length=3;
ubuntu@ip-172-31-28-53:~/playground$ for ((i=0;i<=length;i++));do echo $i;done
0
1
2
3
```

Answer (score 9):

Brace subtitutions are performed before any other, so you need to use `eval` or 
a third-party tool like `seq`.

Example for eval:

```
for i in `eval echo {0..$length}`; do echo $i; done
```

This information can actually be found in `man bash`:

> A sequence expression takes the form {x..y[..incr]}, **where x  and  y  are  either
>    integers  or  single  characters**, and incr, an optional increment, is an integer.
>    [...]
>
> **Brace expansion is performed before any other expansions, and any characters special 
>    to other expansions are preserved in the result.**  It  is  strictly  textual.
>    Bash  does not apply any syntactic interpretation to the context of the expansion
>    or the text between the braces.