# Bash looping with arguments

Tags: bash, loops, command-line-arguments

I'm trying to pass an argument to a bash script and have it iterate through letters

```
    #!/bin/bash
    for l in {$1..$2}; do
         echo $l
    done
```

When I try to run ./myscript.sh A D
Instead of getting:

```
A
B
C
D
```

I get:

```
{A..D}
```

Comment: See: [How to use variables in a bash for loop](http://stackoverflow.com/q/17181787/3776858)

Comment: That's awesome guys thanks, much appreciated!