# for i in {1..$number} acting wierd

Tags: shell

I have a for loop like this:

```sh
    for i in {1..$number}
    do
    echo "Chose a file"
    git apply $(zenity --file-selection --file-filter='patch files (patch) | *.patch' --title="Select your patch file")
done
```

The purpose of the code is for the user to input a file, and it will patch that file. It is supposed to do it multiple times, but it only does it once. I will not post the output, since the error is from the "git apply" and not the for i in {1..$number"}
I can't figure out what is wrong. Can anyone help?

Comment: What is the value of `$number`, where does it come from?

Comment: @Gaël J The value of $number varies. I have a "read number" line that asks for the amount of patches. I am also having a problem with that, but I might ask it later. In my test, I set $number to 5.

Comment: fix your title. Is weird not wierd.

Comment: I assume you are using `bash`; brace expansion happens before parameter expansion, so the value of `$number` isn't known yet.

Answer (score -1, accepted):

**For-in** loop with variable is something complex, not intuitive at all:

```
for i in $( eval echo {0..$number} )
do
    echo "Chose a file"
done
```

[image]

source:

https://stackoverflow.com/a/17181832/3957754

If you want something more readable use this:

```
for (( c=1; c<=$number; c++ ))
do  
   echo "Welcome $c times"
done
```

[image]

In this you will find more loop samples

https://www.cyberciti.biz/faq/bash-for-loop/

Comment: There's no reason to use `eval` in place of the C-style `for` loop.

Comment: But the question is related to the use of variable in the **for-in** style

Comment: And the solution is to *not* use the basic `for` loop. There's really no reason to *ever* use the basic `for` loop with brace expansions. Either the C-style loop is available, and you can iterate without having to create a potentially sizable list in memory before iterating, or the C-style loop is *not* available, in which case brace expansion probably isn't either and you need to use a `while` loop anyway.